# Is primary index created on clustering column of a compound primary key in cassandra?

Tags: indexing, cassandra, cql

Is primary index created on clustering column of a compound primary key in cassandra? If not, what performance benefit we get by creating secondary index on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an index is not automatically created on the clustering column of a composite key.

If you created a secondary index on the clustering column you would actually suffer a performance hit when querying by it.  Secondary indexes in Cassandra exist for convenience, not for performance.  The bottom line is that they don't scale well, and a single query usually ends up having to hit several nodes in your cluster.

Comment: Yes moreover, the query, it will ends up hitting all the nodes. As each node only indexes data that it holds locally. So it ends up asking all nodes.

Comment: You can, of course, mitigate the impact of an otherwise appropriate secondary index query if you restrict it to a single partition.

Comment: @CalebRackliffe True.  But in this case if you have a partition key and single clustering key, and you provide both in your query; then you don't need to add a secondary index to begin with.

Comment: @Aaron Agreed. It's a narrow usage of a rarely appropriate feature.